# Ignore fields to map in response from controller in Contract Tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-contract

As I'm only interested in checking some of the values from the response for my Contract Test, I want to leave out those fields that are not important to me. Thing is that when I run the test, generated test file checks if body defined in the **test.groovy** file is identical to the one generated from controller. So, my question is if there's a way to just assert those values that I'm interested in.

**test.groovy**

```
Contract.make {
    request {
        method 'GET'
        urlPath('/api/node') {
            queryParameters {
                parameter('number', '123')
                parameter('size', '1')
                parameter('status', 'ACTIVE')
            }
        }
        headers {
            header("key", "someKey")
        }
    }
    response {
        status 200
        headers {
            contentType applicationJson()
        }
        body("""
  "content":[
     {
        "id": "123456",
        "status":"ACTIVE",
        "details":[
           {
              "object":{
                 "id":"ccId",
                 "codeOne":"1",
                 "codeTwo":"2",
                 "codeThree":"3",
                 "_links":{
                    "self":{
                       "href":"https://url.com"                        
                    },
                    "style":{
                       "href":"https://universal-url.com"

                    },
                    "universalStyle":{
                       "href":"https://universal-style-v1-url.com"                      
                    }                  
                 }              
              }
              "code":null              
           }            
        ]
```

This is the error I'm getting

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<"[content]"> but was:
<"[{"links":[
{"rel":"first","href":"http://localhost/api/node?number=123&status=ACTIVE&page=0&size=1"},
{"rel":"prev","href":"http://localhost/api/node?number=123&status=ACTIVE&page=0&size=1"},
{"rel":"self","href":"http://localhost/api/node?number=123&size=1&status=ACTIVE"},
{"rel":"last","href":"http://localhost/api/node?number=123&status=ACTIVE&page=1&size=1"}],
"content":[{"id":"123456",...
```

In this case, I don't want to verify any related to "links" array. Is there any configuration I can use in order to bypass it?

Answer (score 0):

Just don't put them in the response and they won't get generated.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't putting them but they were being added anyway as the controller add those values to wrap the response.
But I was able to solve the issue, I needed to wrap my **content** array inside curly braces and now test is passing.